# Styling Accordion tab dash bootstrap component

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I would like to change the tab colour and alignment to centralise it. Thus far I've been using

style = {'textAlign': 'center'} and displace = flex option as well but that skews the content alignment.

Anyone knows how to use CSS to overwrite the title(item 1 , item 2 and item 3 in this case) in the tab only

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

accordion = html.Div(
    dbc.Accordion(
        [
            dbc.AccordionItem(
                [
                    html.P("This is the content of the first section"),
                    dbc.Button("Click here"),
                ],
                title="Item 1",
            ),
            dbc.AccordionItem(
                [
                    html.P("This is the content of the second section"),
                    dbc.Button("Don't click me!", color="danger"),
                ],
                title="Item 2",
            ),
            dbc.AccordionItem(
                "This is the content of the third section",
                title="Item 3",
            ),
        ],
    )
)
```

https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the styling for `.accordion-button` to this:

```
.accordion-button {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Place this in a `.css` file under the `assets` which should be placed on the same directory level as your application file.

Comment: That's what I was looking for thank you.

Comment: Great! Perhaps you can flag this as the answer so other users are aware this solves your issue? Cheers