# Styling Accordion dash bootstrap component

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I would like to customize the tabs in the [accordion bootstrap component](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/accordion/).

This is the code:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

accordion = html.Div(
    dbc.Accordion(
        [
            dbc.AccordionItem(
                "This is the content of the first section", title="Item 1"
            ),
            dbc.AccordionItem(
                "This is the content of the second section", title="Item 2"
            ),
            dbc.AccordionItem(
                "This is the content of the third section", title="Item 3"
            ),
        ],
        start_collapsed=True,
    ),
)
```

rendering this:
[image]

I hev two ajdustments I want to make:

1. Set the title (eg. Item 1) to  H1, or something else.
2. When accordion is activated (open) the default color of the tab is light blue (see screenshot). I want to change this color. How?

I have tried different variations of css styling, like what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775795/styling-accordion-tab-dash-bootstrap-component), but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the Item styling, you need to change the styling for `.accordion-button`. To adjust the styling when opening an accordion item, you need to change the styling for `.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)`.

Here is an example of making the "Item" text larger, and changing the color of the item on opening to red:

```
.accordion-button {
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
    background-color: red;
}
```